# PyOpenGL/OpenGL Generating Cosmic NBodys

Tags: python, simulation, c

I am working on a Universe Simulator. I'm stuck on creating the dark matters webs of the universe that look like this: http://www.mpa-garching.mpg.de/galform/data_vis/sim3dnew-highres.png I am generating the particles as solid spheres with the radius of 1. How can I make the particles slowly move toward each other as demonstrated in the picture above to form "webs" of these particles? If anyone has any ideas or might have some examples of how this can be done that would be great. Code in either c/c++/python would be great. (I have the first step of the picture done) Here is a picture of what I have done: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD4YQ.png

Comment: Note that you're expecting your simple, expectedly real-time toy to reproduce the dynamics of a system modeled by ten billion particles and simulated on a leadership-class machine.  You haven't stated the physics that you're going to reproduce or methods that you're interested in.  We're going to need more to go on here.

Comment: Not quite. The physics I am in need of help with is: Creating a force emitted by each particle to attract other particles toward it to form a web of these particles.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

- Adventures in PyOpenCL: (http://enja.org/category/tutorial/advcl/)
- "nbody simulation using pyopencl and pyopengl": (http://www.firstpost.com/topic/person/nvidia-nbody-simulation-using-pyopencl-and-pyopengl-video-xeOUxTSjowY-7106-7.html)

If you want to program it in python, You might need:

- PyOpenCL (http://mathema.tician.de/software/pyopencl/)
- PyOpenGL (http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/)